# Problem in using font in Inkscape with Nexusfont!

Tags: fonts, inkscape

I have been trying to use fonts from [here](http://luc.devroye.org/pape/) using Nexusfont in Inkscape. However, whenever I try to write using any of these fonts, I dont get the font. Instead, Inkscape displays some generic font. (I am not using my own computer, so I cannot upload an example).

Is this due to the fonts on the website, or are there some compatibility issues between Nexusfont and Inkscape?

Answer (score 2):

As of Inkscape 0.91, this is caused by [bug #1416674](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/1416674).

Based on the comments, there are a few workarounds, depending on where your fonts are stored, such as [this one below](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/1416674/comments/12):

> I fixed this by editing Inkscape\etc\fonts\conf.d\51-local.conf by adding d:\fonts\ between  and 
>   where d:\fonts\ is my font directory
>
> Changing WINDOWSFONTDIR to d:\fonts\ in Inkscape\etc\fonts\fonts.conf makes Inkscape to ignore the system fonts (if you want to see only the custom fonts list)

I'm not familiar with Nexusfont, but I'd suspect that it's doing something the C:\Windows\Fonts that is making system fonts not available to Inkscape, so changing Inkscape to point to wherever the font files are stored as above should probably work.

Comment: Well, that did not work... It still does not show me the fonts.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a full working example using a Google font unpacked to *C:\Fonts*:

`C:\Program Files\Inkscape\etc\fonts\conf.d\51-local.conf`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
    <!-- Load local system customization file -->
    <include ignore_missing="yes">local.conf</include>
    <dir>C:/Fonts</dir>
</fontconfig>
```

Tested on Win7 x64, Inkscape 0.92 x64.
Thank you so much @Scribblemacher for digging up that bug report.

Comment: I can confirm that this solution works on Win10 x64, with Inkscape 0.92.4. I installed two ttf fonts the normal way (from Explorer), and even though they were automatically recognized by Microsoft Word, NotePad etc., the font list in Inkscape wasn't updated (neither by restarting Inkscape nor by rebooting Windows). But after I put them in a font directory under my user directory, and added the path of this font directory to 51-local.conf, the new fonts appeared in Inkscape's font list. Thanks!